# Path selection for object avoidance in Moveit!

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone.

I would like to use Moveit! to avoid obstacles with a robot arm.
I was wondering if there is a way to specify how to avoid obstacles in that case.

For example, when avoiding a cylindrical obstacle, if there is no problem with the arm's range of motion

- Course 1: Go around in front of the obstacle
- Course 2: Go over the obstacle

Both of these courses can be realized in Moveit!, right?

I would like to limit this course to one or the other.
Is such a thing possible?

Thank you:D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370509/path-selection-for-object-avoidance-in-moveit!/) by [mike_popcorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/68839/mike_popcorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the robot can find trajectories along those paths then sure, it's possible. But I don't think that there is a convenient way in MoveIt to specify "through-point goals" like you seem to imagine (except as waypoints for cartesian interpolations), so you would have to plan in multiple steps and concatenate the trajectories.

Pull requests to implement intermediate goals are welcome.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mike_popcorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/68839/mike_popcorn/) on 2021-01-29**:
Thank you for answering my question.
For now, I would like to generate a multi-step trajectories.
I'm still a beginner, but I'll do my best.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-01-30**:
Good luck, and feel free to post follow-up questions when you get stuck.